# CS8804: Cannot specify /main if there is a compilation unit with top-level statements

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

searching "C# compilation unit" does not reveal any useful results around the internet

Comment: It's very hard to help without *any* context of what you're trying to achieve. Ideally, provide a [mcve] with more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want the question to be reopened, you must include the relevant code into your question, so that we see where exactly the error is and can give you a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have written some statements outside of any method or class. These statements are interpreted as top-level statements. Top-level statements are automatically enclosed in a compiler generated main method. Since you cannot add another main method, you can use top-level only once.

Resolution: move these top-level statements in a method inside a class.

See:

- [What's new in C# 9.0 / Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)
- [Tutorial: Explore ideas using top-level statements to build code as you learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/top-level-statements)
- [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/)

Comment: thank you ,and i cross check my Win Desktop Application installation now its fine working